# TypeError: serialport.parsers.readline is not a function error

Tags: node.js, npm, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port

This is my code

```
    var webSocketUrl = "wss://api.artik.cloud/v1.1/websocket?ack=true";
    var device_id = "########################"; //  DEVICE ID
    var device_token = "#####################"; // DEVICE TOKEN

   // require websocket module to connect 
   // execute following two commands to your pi's terminal
   // sudo apt-get update
   // npm install websocket
  var WebSocket = require('ws');
  var isWebSocketReady = false;
  var data="";
  var ws = null;
 // require serialport module to raspberry pi 
 // execute following command to terminal
 // npm install serialport
 var serialport = require("serialport");
 var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
 var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", { //for serial communication with 
 arduino 
 baudrate: 9600,  
 // we are using UNO so baudrate is 9600, you might need to change according 
 to your model
 parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
 });
```

But after i run this i got a error like this

```
 /home/pi/parking.js:21
 parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
                           ^

TypeError: serialport.parsers.readline is not a function
 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/rainbow-parking.js:21:32)
 at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
 at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
 at startup (node.js:140:18)
 at node.js:1043:3
```

Anyone can help me to solve this problem.I tried a lot. I this problem is with my nodejs and npm version problem.But not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong variable name. Instead of

> serialport.parsers.readline

Use

> Serialport.parsers.readline

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using very old, Have a look at the docs https://node-serialport.github.io/node-serialport/global.html#Parsers your code is using them a very old way.

Replace this part of your code

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", { 
//for serial communication with arduino 
baudrate: 9600,  
// we are using UNO so baudrate is 9600, you might need to change according to your model
parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
});
```

with the below mentioned code

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const port = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0",{
    baudRate: 9600,
    parser: new Readline("\n")
});
```

Comment: link appears to be outdated -- https://serialport.io/docs/api-overview#parsers is new documentation on the matter

Answer (score 0):

okay. I found a solution for this problem. The problem was my npm version and serial port versions are not matching with each other. Easily avoid this problem updating those 2 versions same. Thank you everyone for the help